# Changing the style of an element after it is appended doesn't trigger transition from the style that it was appended with

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Reproducing this took me a night, this is the most tidy version I could came up
with.

Its pretty easy to explain the behaviour:

1. to change the flow, an element in the DOM is appended to a different location
2. positioning it isn't based on the flow, so the style is changed after too

No problem with it. Check the demo. For a naked eye:
`swap` - changes numbers in right.
`append` - matches numbers in left with numbers in right.
`positions` - sorts elements by the numbers with *animation*
`swap_append_positions` - does the 3 above but instant (the problem)
`swap_append_positions_timeout` - does the 3 above normally (dirty fix)

*[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va9iff/khspq4d5/3/)*

```js
let $ = new Proxy({}, { get: (_, c) => document.querySelector(`.${c}`) })
// just a fancy wrapper to query classes with $.class syntax.

items = [$.A, $.B, $.C, $.D]

$.positions.onclick = e =>
    items.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.style.top = `${i * 2}rem`
    })

$.swap.onclick = e => {
    items.push(items.shift()) // move the first element to the end
    items.forEach((item, i) => (item.innerText = `${i + 1}`))
}

$.append.onclick = e => {
    let frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
    items.forEach(item => frag.appendChild(item))
    $.container.appendChild(frag)
    // Arrange the elements in the order in the `items` list.
}

$.swap_append_positions.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    $.positions.click()
}

$.swap_append_positions_timeout.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    setTimeout(() => $.positions.click(), 4)
}

$.log.onclick = e => {
    console.log("~")
    items.forEach(item => console.log(`${item.classList[1]} ${item.innerText}`))
}

$.swap_append_positions.click()
```

```css
.item {
    animation-name: added;
    animation-duration: 400ms;

    position: absolute;
    transition: 700ms;

    border: 2px solid coral;
    padding: 0.2rem;
}

.item:before {
    color: navy;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.A:before { content: "A" }
.B:before { content: "B" }
.C:before { content: "C" }
.D:before { content: "D" }

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

@keyframes added{
    from{
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    to{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
    <button class="swap">swap</button>
    <button class="append">append</button>
    <button class="positions">positions</button> <br>

    <button class="swap_append_positions">swap_append_positions</button>
    <button class="log">log</button> <br>
    <button class="swap_append_positions_timeout">swap_append_positions_timeout</button>

    <ol class="container">
      <li class="item A">item 1</li>
      <li class="item B">item 2</li>
      <li class="item C">item 3</li>
      <li class="item D">item 4</li>
    </ol>
```

```js
$.swap_append_positions.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    $.positions.click() // doesn't work
}

$.swap_append_positions_timeout.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    setTimeout(() => $.positions.click(), 4) // works
}
```

- Letter in blue represent the actual element.
- Number in the right (`innerText`) is the index in the array.
- Number in the left is the index for `ol` which represents the child's index in flow.

#### The 3 steps

- `swap` - takes the first element in the array and moves it to the end
  (also reflects the index in the `innerText`)
- `append` - appends and reorganizes the elements in the order in the array.
- `positions` - fixes the positions to match the flow.

This 3 steps is what I needed. Indeed, they work when you press them one-by-one.

But lets press these 3 at once

- `swap_append_positions` - presses `swap` `append`
  `positions` synchronously.
- `swap_append_positions_timeout` - presses `swap` `append`
  synchronously and then schedules `setTimeout` for `positions`.

Weirdly, `swap_append_positions` doesn't work. Intuitively, to me it's like

> when you append and change the style in the "same cycle" there's no chance to
> "render" the element with the old styles as the "cycle" hasn't ended yet, so it
> be like waiting to be rendered. but before it is rendered with the old style,
> we set a new style. so it will be rendered like it's appended with a new style
> and there was no "previous" style for this element to do a transition from.

in short, old state was ignored because I appended it. Don't get me wrong, I'm
not changing anything, just re-appending it. Only after it, I update to new
state. But it ignores the old.

#### The solution I want

I had no idea why was the transition wasn't working and didn't expected that
doing it synchronously would be the problem but somehow I figured it out.
Now I have no idea how to make it work.
I need the properties to be set before the `swap_append_positions_timeout` is
returned. It's like an "update" function for my project.
Don't tell me the ways to get around this nor offer logic to work asynchronously.

I just need to append with the old styles and set the new styles *synchronously* -
which would do a transition from old to new. Obviously, that's not the case.

So if you have something to explain this behaviour than my fool's assumption, I'd
like to hear please. If you have a solution, that'd be great. Else, thanks for the
effort that you have read till there.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: 'there wasn't the button' - could you edit your question and look for the <> button - are you saying it isn't there? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help.

Comment: @AHaworth now it was there. there was a table button instead of `<>`

Answer (score 0):

You say that

```
$.swap_append_positions_timeout.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    setTimeout(() => $.positions.click(), 4) // works
}
```

works (i.e. there is a transition).

whereas

```
$.swap_append_positions.onclick = e => {
    $.swap.click()
    $.append.click()
    $.positions.click() // doesn't work
}
```

does not work.

In the not working code the system doesn't 'know' about the initial appended style, the JavaScript completes before it gets to have a look, by which time the new styling is in place.

In the working code, the system gets a chance to see the original styling as the JS has given up running for a bit so when the JS sets the styling to something else after the timeout the system can see there has been a change and the transition takes place.

Incidentally, on many systems (I'm not sure whether all), a timeout time of 0 will make sure the system 'knows' there has been a change.

Comment: using timeout with 0 or 4 doesn't matter for me. anyways, the thing I want is to reorganize some elements and then assign them a different style which will cause them to do a transition from the old. maybe append isn't the right way? or is it possible to make it? or like moving an element to a different location that has a css class which has an animation (keyframes) cause logically, moving an element shouldn't trigger it. I feel like append is the wrong way but I don't know :/

Comment: However you reorganise the elements in the DOM, to make a transition happen you need to show the system two states between which it can transition. That’s what your setTimeout is enabling. You may like to investigate requestAnimationFrame, but essentially it’s doing a similar thing.

Comment: assigning after the next line has been executed isn't what I want. and I do understand that transition needs 2 states to go from one to the next. my goal was to go from the state of the element when it was appended (1), to the the new one that I set (2) but it looks impossible. why not just setting? cuz I'll swap `li` to say 3rd index in ui and will set its `top` accordingly but using `tab` for focusing will work by the in the flow afaik. anyways, I just need to sync flow of html and do a transition which will represent their move in the document. no synchronous way???

Comment: Hi, I don't entirely understand what the problem is. You have to give the system the chance to render the first state so (to put it simplisticly) you have to come out of the JS to let it have a go at rendering.

Comment: in the most simple way - I only want to **move** an element position in the flow of the parent element and make it don't _rerender._ it won't _forget_ the state 1 so I can set state 2 and be happy with my transition and even my css animations won't replay

Comment: Same problem with replaying animmations, you have to give the system a chance to see the animation has been removed before you put  it back on again. Something has to be rerendered. I don't think I can help any more as I'm not understanding why a rerender is out of the question for you.

Comment: I'm not trying to add or remove animations. the core of my problem is that - If I move an element to a different position (in the dom flow) It gets rerendered. I just wanted to prevent this. as far as I understand, there's no such way. moving and appending a new element is treated exactly the same.and "system wanting a chance" won't let me to do a workaround by reassigning it before. another way that comes to my mind is - can I "force" it to rerender, so I can have state 1 rendered then assign a state 2 by hand for a particular element?